# What does Mongo DB error code 14809 mean?

Tags: mongodb

I occasionally get this error code returned when trying to do mapreduce operations.  The error message from Mongo is "Invalid access for cursor that is not ok()".

Retrying the operation seems to work. Is there a way I can prevent this error in the first place or do I just need to watch for it and retry later?

Comment: Not sure how you open your cursor in the map/reduction process but I will try to keep the cursor open in this case using a cursor option (DBQuery.Option.noTimeout). It seems the server is closing your cursor due to a timeout.

Comment: It's with the Mongoid ORM in Ruby, so I'm not managing any of that manaully. If it's a timeout issue then I would assume doing a short wait and a retry will often mitigate this error?

Comment: I remember Ruby has a mechanism to set timeout options. In my case I have a solution in Python that doesn't change timeout due to server requirements and yes, I had to manually solve this problem. In my case when I detect a cursor expired I restart and skip N records tracked down previously to restart the process.